# Current / Previous / Previous -- A term to describe this state other than tense or currency

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a term to describe a state.  Ordinarily I would use the word "Currency" to describe the state of "Current", "Future", "Previous", however in the context, this would be too easily confused with a monetary currency.

What would be another good word to use to describe a "currency" state?

"The currency of the address" sounds and reads horribly, and certainly "tense" in this context doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Rocksalt. Can't you use 'status'? Since you are describing a state.

Comment: Potentially... would prefer a better term that directly implies currency.  Status/State is generic and certainly in the context where I need the term would also be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly **[recency](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recency)** or **recentness**

> [the quality of] having appeared, happened, or been made not long ago; modern, fresh, or new

While the terms suggest *close to the present*, they might provide a reference point as in

> *What is the recency of that event?*

Answer (score 0):

Some of the IT folk down here in Jamaica seek data fields or data elements which are TEMPORAL in nature, adding context of time, e.g., insert_datetime, update_datetime.  So that is another adjective which MAY fit......